# How to modify a property of a constructor function?

Tags: javascript

I want to modify the "name" property by adding a prefix "with suggar" and adding +1 to cost. Without adding the property: "coffee.sugar" to the method: "this.toString"

```js
function Coffe(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = function () {
            return 5;
        };
        this.toString = function () {
            return this.name + this.cost() + 'USD';
        }
    }
 var sugar = function () {
        coffe.sugar = "with sugar ";
      var cost = coffe.cost();
        coffe.cost = function () {
            return cost + 1;
        }
    };
 var coffe = new Coffe('Latte');
    sugar(coffe);
    console.log(coffe.cost());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reassign the `name` property:

```js
function Coffe(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = function () {
            return 5;
        };
        this.toString = function () {
            return this.name + this.cost() + 'USD';
        }
    }
 var sugar = function (coffe) {
      coffe.name = "with sugar " + coffe.name;
      var cost = coffe.cost();
        coffe.cost = function () {
            return cost + 1;
        }
    };
 var coffe = new Coffe('Latte');
    sugar(coffe);
    console.log(coffe.name);
    console.log(coffe.cost());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sugar method takes a no arguments, but you're passing your `coffee` instance in.  Just change the name property of the passed instance like so:

```js
function Coffe(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = function () {
            return 5;
        };
        this.toString = function () {
            return this.name + this.cost() + 'USD';
        }
    }
 var sugar = function (coffe) {
        coffe.name += " with sugar";
      var cost = coffe.cost();
        coffe.cost = function () {
            return cost + 1;
        }
    };
 var coffe = new Coffe('Latte');
    sugar(coffe);
    console.log(coffe.cost());
    console.log(coffe.name);
```